# Need some help starting off with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am starting off with mongodb and need some help getting some facts straight before I can continue to work on this project.  The questions are listed below, and I appreciate any and all answers :)

Thanks!

1. How do you create a collection in advanced? From what i understood
   the collection gets created when you insert a document for the first
   time.
2. And what types of indexes are there?
3. Lastly, there are no joins in mongodb like there are in mysql. Let's say i'm trying to build a
   basic private messaging system. I want to have 2 collections
   (tables). One that lists the participants in a conversation, a
   unique id for the conversation, and another collection for all of
   the messages for that conversation. In mongodb is it wiser to nest
   the second collectino into the first as a sub-column such as
   "messages"? Or am i better off keeping them separate? Is it possible to update a subcolumn with new rows? let me link a quick exmaple of what i am talking about 
   http://pastebin.com/gzKDNwnU

Comment: Me too, me too, thanks for this question.

Comment: While not attempting to answer, Mongo is object oriented. It recognizes the fact that we don't really care about tables. In your case, you will have a class `User`, and a class `Conversation`, which has multiple posts, as an orderd list by time. And each post should also have its class `Post`, and belong to a particular `User` instance. And Mongo takes care simply of persiting this object structure, as far as I have, being a noob, understood.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky MongoDB should not be confused with an OO database, it is a document store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create collections in advance.  There exists a createCollection command due to the fact that certain special collections (like capped collections) do require some parameters to be specified in advance.  Collection will also be created when you create or 'ensureIndex' on some field(s) in it.

The index types are documented at [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/).

I would recommend **against** embedding into documents any series of documents that can continue growing unbounded.  It would be better to denormalize some of the information from your conversation collection into messages collection (if necessary).  Remember the goal is to be able to get in one read all or most of the information you will usually need and not more.  So it's not the data that determines the schema, it's your application access patterns.

Comment: So you would recommend the format I posted in my pastebin link and use the $push to add things to the end of the array of messages?  Will only be 1 read when trying to get a conversation then.

Comment: no, that's the opposite of what I recommend.  I recommend NOT embedding messages in the conversations.

Comment: Whoops, got normalize and de-normalize backwards, my bad.  So that would be two reads then.  Also a seperate question, but how do people normally query for a conversation for instance when the only thing to grab it by is _id?  I assume the uuid isn't used on the html for the links, so what would you recommend?

Comment: While it greatly depends on specific use cases, a lot of people generate a slug (short unique string) to identify a conversation (or a web page, or a product, etc.)